# Update only specific fields in a models.Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-database

I have a model

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    active = models.NullBooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```

and now I want to update only the `active` field. So I do this:

```
survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, created_by=request.user, pk=question_id)
survey.active = True
survey.save(["active"])
```

Now I get an error `IntegrityError: PRIMARY KEY must be unique`.

Am I right with this method to update?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

To update a subset of fields, you can use [`update_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save):

```
survey.save(update_fields=["active"])
```

The `update_fields` argument was added in Django 1.5. In earlier versions, you could use the [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update) method instead:

```
Survey.objects.filter(pk=survey.pk).update(active=True)
```

Comment: While this answer makes `.update()` sound deprecated, both update methods are still available and non-deprecated as of Django 4.0. Great answer for mentioning both options, though :-)

Comment: This won't update the `auto_now` field
`modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`
have to specify like below
`survey.save(update_fields=["active", "modified_at"])`

Comment: .update() may not be deprecated, but it apparently does not trigger model_observer, which is important in async implementations.  In that case, save(update_fields=[...]) is needed

Answer (score 22):

Usually, the correct way of updating certain fields in one or more model instances is to use the [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#update) method on the respective queryset. Then you do something like this:

```
affected_surveys = Survey.objects.filter(
    # restrict your queryset by whatever fits you
    # ...
    ).update(active=True)
```

This way, you don't need to call `save()` on your model anymore because it gets saved automatically. Also, the `update()` method returns the number of survey instances that were affected by your update.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with `.get` instead of `.filter` and this doesn't work. But with filter it works nice.
Do you know what is wrong with my code above?

Comment: Your problem might be related to `question_id`. Where does this value come from? And which exact line does raise the `IntegrityError`?

Comment: `question_id` comes from urls `(?P<question_id>\d+)`. My fault was that on the working server django 1.4 is installed and my code is 1.5. But with your code it's working fine.

Comment: @RegisteredUser, looks like there's no "update" method on objects, just on querysets.  When you use .filter(), you get a queryset (holding zero or more objects) back.  When you use .get() you get a single object.

Comment: By default, calling `save()` (@Alasdair solution) is a safer solution, because this method may triggers things like validation, or any custom code, than `update()` does not.

Comment: This won't update the `auto_now` field
`modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`
have to specify like below
`survey.save(update_fields=["active", "modified_at"])`

Comment: .update() apparently does not trigger model_observer, which is important in async implementations. In that case, save(update_fields=[...]) is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this mixin that can be used to detect which fields have changed in a model instance and pass that information to the save method. Here is a description of the mixin:

- In the **init** method, the mixin initializes a dictionary called old_instance_data which stores the initial values of the fields in the model instance.
- In the save method, the mixin compares the current values of the fields with the initial values stored in old_instance_data to determine which fields have changed. It creates a set of update_fields containing the names of the changed fields.
- If the model instance has a primary key (self.pk is not None), the mixin automatically determines the changed fields if update_fields is not explicitly provided.
- The mixin then calls the save method of the parent class, passing the update_fields to it, along with any other keyword arguments that may be provided.
- If you pass your own update_fields parameter when saving, it use this one. Thus you can partially use other update_fields anywhere in your code.

By using this mixin in a model, you can conveniently track and save only the fields that have been modified, which can be helpful for optimizing database updates and reducing unnecessary database queries.

```py
from django.db import models


class UpdateFieldsMixin(models.Model):
    """ Detects which field changed and passes it to save method """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        fields = (field.name for field in self._meta.fields)
        self.old_instance_data = {name: getattr(self, name, None)
                                  for name in fields}

    def save(self, update_fields=None, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            update_fields = update_fields or {
                k for k, v in self.old_instance_data.items()
                if getattr(self, k, None) != v}
        return super().save(update_fields=update_fields, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Use it like:

```py
class YourModel(UpdateFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    # Any code

    def save(**kwargs):
        # Any code
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

That's all. If you have a custom save method, make sure you call UpdateFieldsMixin.save. I'd suggest using super() like in the example above.